# How to reproduce clang's -O2 optimizations with LLVM tools?

Tags: llvm

Suppose I generate an unoptimized `foo.ll` using `clang -S -emit-llvm foo.c`.

What steps do I need to take to get from `foo.ll` to `optimized.s` that's optimized as if it was produced by `clang` directly using `-O2`?

(`opt -S -O2 foo.ll -o optimized.ll; llc optimized.ll` is not it.)

Answer (score 0):

You can compile using

```
llc -O2 -optimize-regalloc foo.ll
```

`-optimize-regalloc` allows better physical register allocation.

Answer (score 0):

The command `clang -S -emit-llvm foo.c` will produce a `foo.ll` file full of optimization restrictions in such a way that if you later do `llc foo.ll` you will get almost the same output as `clang -S foo.c`.

To be able to optimize `foo.ll` you need to get rid of those optimization restrictions in the first place.

As an example, suppose you have the following simple C program:

```c
int zero()
{
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    return zero();
}
```

Your do `clang -S -emit-llvm zero.c` to produce the file `zero.ll` which looks like this (some lines clipped at begin and end)

```
define dso_local i32 @zero() #0 {
  ret i32 0
}

define dso_local i32 @main() #0 {
  %1 = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 0, i32* %1, align 4
  %2 = call i32 @zero()
  ret i32 %2
}

attributes #0 = { noinline nounwind optnone uwtable }
```

The most important line here is the last one which are attributes applying to every functions and in particular `noinline` which prevent function inlining and `optnone` which prevent function optimization.

You need to erase this line (or these lines):

```bash
grep -v "^attributes " zero.ll > zero_trimmed.ll
```

Then you can apply optimizations:

```bash
opt -S -O2 zero_trimmed.ll > zero_optimized.ll
```

In `zero_optimized.ll` the `main` function has been completely optimized:

```
define dso_local i32 @main() local_unnamed_addr #0 {
  ret i32 0
}
```

Then you can do `llc zero_optimized.ll` to get `zero_optimized.s`:

Now if you compare the output of `zero_optimized.s` to the output of `clang -S -O2 zero.c` you get:

```bash
 diff zero.s zero_optimized.s
7d6
<       .cfi_startproc
13d11
<       .cfi_endproc
19d16
<       .cfi_startproc
25d21
<       .cfi_endproc
29d24
<       .addrsig
```

These are not real assembly instructions, but only directives with very little or no effect on the code generated (cfi_ is for debugging purpose I think).